# Botão HTML ir para link

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, sou iniciante e gostaria de saber como redireciono esse botão(Assinar) de habilitar termos de uso para algum link.

```
<div class="modal-body">
     <!--botão termos de uso-->
     <script>   
         function HabiDsabi(){  
             if(document.getElementById('habi').checked == true){ 
                 document.getElementById('envia').disabled = ""  
             }  
             if(document.getElementById('habi').checked == false){ 
                 document.getElementById('envia').disabled = "disabled"  

            }
         }
     </script>
     <form name="form1">
         <p>
             <input type="checkbox" name="habi" id="habi" onClick="HabiDsabi()"> 
             Eu li e aceito os termos de uso 
             <a target="_blank" href="tos.html">termos de uso<a>.
         </p>
         <input type="button" class="btn btn-terciary"  name="envia" id="envia" value="Assinar" disabled>
     </form>
     <!-- fim do botão -->
</div>
```

Comment: Se é para redirecionar para outra página, use o `<a>` com o atributo `href`.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, você esta querendo redirecionar o usuário para um link quando ele clicar no botão e estiver com checbox marcado, correto ?
Se for isso, dentro da sua função HabiDsabi(){}, quando for para redirecionar é só usar está função ( window.open( URL, name, Specs ) )

Caso seja isso, para maiores informações consulte: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/open-a-link-without-clicking-on-it-using-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função com o metodo `window.location.href = "URLaSerRedirecionada";` e chamar esse função no click, ou chamar o método direto 
 com `onclick`;

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com'">link</button>
```

Comment: Onde posso colocar o '_blank' para abrir em uma nova aba?

Comment: para abir em outra aba direto do botão você pode usar o `window.open`, exemplo:
`<button onclick="window.open('http://pt.stackoverflow.com');">link</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode redirecionar utilizando window.location no onclick confome abaixo:

```js
function HabiDsabi() {
  if (document.getElementById('habi').checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('envia').disabled = ""
  }
  if (document.getElementById('habi').checked == false) {
    document.getElementById('envia').disabled = "disabled"
  }
}

function assinar(){
  window.location.href = "minhaNovaPagina.html"
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">

<form name="form1">


<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="habi" id="habi" onClick="HabiDsabi()"> Eu li e aceito os termos de uso 
    <a target="_blank" href="tos.html">termos de uso</a>.
  </p>
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-terciary"  name="envia" id="envia" value="Assinar" onclick="assinar()" disabled></form>
<!-- fim do botão -->
</div>
```

Veja mais sobre window.location em https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score -1):

Apenas como uma alternativa, as respostas atuais já fazem o que você deseja.
Esta não utiliza javascript, apenas html e css opcionalmente.

```html
<button><a target="_blank" href='https://pt.stackoverflow.com'>Click me!</a> </button>
```

Você pode colocar um pouco de css para deixar o `<a>` como um texto normal também se quiser.

```css
a {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button><a target="_blank" href='https://pt.stackoverflow.com'>Click me!</a> </button>
```

Lembrando que não é a melhor forma de se fazer, apenas um método alternativo.